# why does asm expect a () when the line is already balanced

Tags: c++

I am trying to build and then run the demo for kinfu_remake https://github.com/Nerei/kinfu_remake

running windows 10,   cmake3.14.3, MS visual studio 2017

I running into an error building these particular lines (device.hpp line 132):

```
    template<> __kf_device__ void kfusion::device::gmem::StCs(const TsdfVolume::elem_type& val, TsdfVolume::elem_type*& ptr)
    {
        short cx = val.x, cy = val.y;
        asm("st.global.cs.v2.u16 [%0], {%1, %2};" : "="_ASM_PTR_(ptr) : "h"(reinterpret_cast<ushort&>(cx)), "h"(reinterpret_cast<ushort&>(cy)));
    }
```

error reads: expected a ")"

The ()s seem to be balanced, so I am not sure what is causing this problem. I looked around and saw some people running into errors with if statements that needed ()s but I don't think that's the problem here for a couple reasons. 
1) i placed () around anything that might need it and 
2) after commenting out this line, the code successfully built leading me to believe the error is in this particular line. (obviously commenting out isn't a solution because I need the line to successfully execute)

I don't have a lot of experience with the asm command, and would appreciate any advice on how to proceed.

Comment: `__kf_device__` is a name reserved for the impletation. Don't use such names in your own code.

Comment: Why are you using inline asm in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

What is causing this problem is the simple fact that the GCC `asm` syntax your code above is using is non-standard and, thus, not understood by Visual C++. The "official" syntax for an `asm` declaration is [[dcl.asm]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.asm#1):

*attribute-specifier-seq*<sub>opt</sub> `asm` ( *string-literal* ) ;

Apart from this, `asm` declarations are only [conditionally supported](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/defns.cond.supp) [[dcl.asm]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.asm#1), that means that there is no requirement from the standard that a compiler has to support `asm` declarations. If a compiler does support `asm` declarations, the meaning is implementation-defined. The [documented behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/inline/asm?view=vs-2019) of `asm` declarations on Visual C++ is that the compiler will silently eat it but

> […] not generate any meaningful code. […]

Visual C++ has its own non-standard [`__asm` keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/inline/asm?view=vs-2019), but the syntax for that is completely different and inline assembly [is actually only supported when targeting 32-Bit x86](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/inline/inline-assembler?view=vs-2019)…

Apart from all that, the assembly in your code above appears to be [PTX assembly](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html), which would suggest that you're attempting to compile CUDA GPU code with Visual C++. That is obviously not going to work. You need to compile your CUDA code with a CUDA-capable compiler. Most likely, there is something wrong with your build configuration…